# How do I avoid these repetitions when using recursive make?

Tags: makefile, dry

Suppose I have a project with two or more subfolders `foo`, `bar`, etc. I have a `Makefile` at the root of the project, and also in each subdirectory.

I would like to have certain targets (e.g. `all`, `clean`, etc) to run recursively in each subdirectory. My top-level `Makefile` looks like this:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C foo all
    $(MAKE) -C bar all

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C foo clean
    $(MAKE) -C bar clean
```

Seems to me there's a lot of duplication going on here. **Is there a way I can avoid such tedious duplication in my Makefiles?**

Comment: Is there a reason for not using automake?

Comment: @awoodland not necessarily, what would be the benefit?

Comment: The benefit is you get all that kind of stuff written for you :)

Comment: Heresy: https://github.com/apenwarr/redo

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SUBDIRS=foo bar
all clean:
        for dir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
            $(MAKE) -C $$dir $@ ; \
        done
```

Comment: @reprogrammer: the problem is not recursive make as a concept, but rather the usual implementation of recursive make such as that found in GNU make.  In contrast Electric Make uses [non-blocking recursive make](http://blog.melski.net/2012/09/04/fixing-recursive-make/) to address the performance issues with recursive make, and [conflict detection and correction](http://blog.melski.net/2011/07/05/how-electricmake-guarantees-reliable-parallel-builds/) to ensure correctness. The net result is that you get the convenience of recursive make _and_ the performance/correctness of non-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

A bit scary:

```
SUBDIRS=foo bar
SUBDIR_TARGETS=all clean

define subdir_rule
$(2): $(1)-$(2)
$(1)-$(2):
    make -C $(1) $(2)
endef

$(foreach targ,$(SUBDIR_TARGETS),\
    $(foreach dir,$(SUBDIRS),\
        $(eval $(call subdir_rule,$(dir),$(targ)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
SUBDIRS=foo bar baz

TARGETS = clean all whatever
.PHONY:$(TARGETS)

# There really should be a way to do this as "$(TARGETS):%:TARG=%" or something...
all: TARG=all
clean: TARG=clean
whatever: TARG=whatever

$(TARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
    @echo $@ done

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    @$(MAKE) -s -C $@ $(TARG)
```